# How to put a high metallic shining gradient border like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient, borders, metallic

I m a beginner and also new to this blog.
 Here is my first question to this awesome and  very helpful forum!
 
I want to put a **metal type shining gradient border** around any shape or square box in **Photoshop** like this below -

[image]

Please give the tut with screenshot if possible, as I m new to Photoshop.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to cover the creation of the gradient itself, as that is more a matter of personal preference, but I will go over the fundamentals of this effect.

In the `Layers Panel`, double-click on the layer that you wish to add this effect to (Gradient Stroke).  Then turn on `Stroke`.  Under `Fill Type` change it from "Color" to "Gradient" and then you can play with your gradient settings, to achieve a metallic effect that pleases you.  If you want to do it the easy way, download some pre-made gradients.

[image: stroke]

The above settings (very simple gradient, just to demonstrate):

[image: result]

*If I may just add my two cents here (since you are new to this), I would take it easier on the Strokes and Drop Shadows.  The black font with yellow stroke hurts my eyes and a drop shadow is not necessary.  I prefer to take a very minimalistic approach to effects and styles; I style my fonts just enough to stand out from the background, without having the effects/styles distract you.  Also that reference image...I wouldn't follow that as an example, that looks very outdated and tacky.

Hope this helps and welcome to GDSE!  While we aren't a tutorial site, we will try our best to point you in the right direction, if you can demonstrate to us what you have tried so far and where you are having trouble.