# How to make metalic borders like these logos in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, background, metallic

I want to create a metallic border in the Photoshop, but i don't know how to do this, here are some examples:

[image: Examples]

I want to the background and border that is below the text.

Comment: 50% gray as the base color and then use dodge tool + burn tool to paint in the highlihts and shadows. It mighr be smart to also use some texture overlays on top of it with  maybe... blend mode multiple or overlay.  I'd try different metallic texture with maybe scratches or peeled paint or like just concretet or rock.

Comment: Made a timelapse video where I recreate a section of that border. [**Link to the video**](https://youtu.be/0TxrhDIHocU). I used ~90% dodge and burn tool with low exposure slowly building it up. Should be noted that I wasn't trying to remake the original border 1 to 1, I just tried to keep it similar to the right side/the overall look. As a side note, doing stuff like this is easier when you make a mental note of where the light source is. Drawing a representation of the light source is also helpful so you don't forget.

Comment: Wow, this was very helpful, awesome video, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photoshop has layer style "Bevel&Emboss" for making fake extrusions. There are many adjustable parameters which make also metallic effects possible. See an example:

[image]

There's an adjustment layer "curves", too because it helps to get good contrast faster.

In 3D category there exists "Repousse". It's a real 3D extrusion modelling and gives more possiblities beyond Bevel&Emboss.

Background is a separate layer.

If you need big apparent extrusion thickness, you have following options

- draw the thickness yourself. Takes time if the text is long, but you can start with a layer where the text is shifted a little. See the image below.
- use 3D > Repousse; it looks out complex, but it's much faster than drawing
- goto another program, for ex. Illustrator has acceptably working 3D effect Extrude&Bevel which is quite simple to use. Unfortunately there's some bugs which sometimes make bevels crappy in extruded texts. It happens if the bevel is at some point too large.

[image]

This is how apparent thickness can be added manually. You must fix only those corners which reveal it's only a flat shadow. It's easier if you rasterize the text. More realism can be achieved by adding some light variations, but it really needs much work. Other methods do it easier.

GDSE has many older discussions about metallic effects. Search for them.

Examples:

[How to put a high metallic shining gradient border like this?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42596/how-to-put-a-high-metallic-shining-gradient-border-like-this)

[Can anyone help me recreate this effect? (3D)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100377/can-anyone-help-me-recreate-this-effect-3d)